# Show multiple apps in selection dialog when calling an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

The usual way to call an external app by an implicit intent is:

```
String myUri = "geo:...";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myUri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Inside an app, the user should be able to select among different apps like Google Maps **and** Google Streetview, which have different [URI patterns](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html).

```
// a Google maps URI may look like:
"geo:latitude,longitude"

// a Google Streetview URI looks like:
"google.streetview:cbll=lat,lng&cbp=1,yaw,,pitch,zoom&mz=mapZoom"
```

Is it possible to set up an intent that results in an app selection dialog that shows Google Maps **and** Google Streetview? As far as I know, there is just one URI for an intent settable. Is there another approach?

A complete different approach would be to set up two buttons inside the starting app, each button calling another intent with the appropriate URI. But right now I am looking for one app selection dialog with a variety of apps.